# R Loop through a group of columns to make several plots

Tags: r, loops, plot

> I need to make several scatter plots from some of the columns on my data frame, so I decided to make a loop, but I don't Know how to set it to iterate just on my columns of interest. 
>   my code looks like this:

```
col_xVScol_y<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=col_x, y=col_y)) + 
geom_point(aes(color= col_z))
```

> col_y and col_z would always be the same, I just need to iterate over a group of columns that would take the place of col_x
>
> I´ve seen that you can iterate over the columns with colnames(), like:

```
for(i in colnames(df)){
    col_xVScol_y<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=col_x, y=col_y)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color= col_z))]
}
```

> But this way is not suitable for my data frame, because it iterates over all columns and I´m interesed in just a group.

Comment: I would reshape the data frame using `pivot_longer` from the `tidyr` package such that all your `col_x` columns (assuming they have unique column names) are stacked into a categorical `names` column and the associated `value` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you could reshape the data frame using `pivot_longer` from the `tidyr` package such that all your `col_x` columns (assuming they have unique column names) are stacked into a categorical column and the associated `values` column. With this you can use `facet_wrap` in your `ggplot` and create a facet plot that produces separate scatter plots for each combination.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

    data <- mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, cyl, disp, hp, wt) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("mpg", "disp", "hp"),
               names_to = "Columns",
               values_to = "Values") 

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Values, y = wt, colour = as.factor(cyl))) +
         geom_point() +
         facet_wrap(. ~ Columns)
```

Looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank yaou!! this was really helpfull

Comment: if this response is useful to you, kindly up-vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating using i, you can iterate using the colnames, as shown below. The call to grid.arrange() from gridExtra is just to plot all the plots in one graphic - you can plot these however you like (storing them in a list is convenient, I find).

The below code iterates over only some columns of mtcars. You could customise this however you like (by constructing the appropriate vector of column names or indices).

```
plot_list <- list()

for(col in colnames(mtcars)[c(9:11)]){

  col_xVScol_y <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 
                  geom_point(aes_string(color = col)) 

  plot_list[[col]] <- col_xVScol_y
}

print(plot_list)

# library(gridExtra)
# grid.arrange(grobs = plot_list)
```

[Output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6qiq.png)